# CloseMainWindow() in Task Scheduler process won't terminate

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I use this simple line in a powershell script to close outlook before doing backup of PST:

```
Get-Process Outlook | %{ $_.CloseMainWindow() } | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogFile
```

It work perfectly from command line but when I put it in task scheduler (Windows 7) Outlook is not closed and the command return "False".

The task is set to run as same user from command line and tried it with High Privileges.

Any one have an idea about that?

Many thanks and best regards,

RiOt

EDIT:
Ok to clarify the situation:

In the Task Scheduler the command is:
batch.bat

with the content of batch.bat:

```
...  
powershell script.ps1  
...
```

The content of script.ps1:

```
...  
Get-Process Outlook | %{ $_.CloseMainWindow() } | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogFile  
...
```

Comment: Note that  

    `Get-Process Outlook`  

return the running Outlook process correctly even in task scheduler it is just the `%{ $_.CloseMainWindow() }` that return false every time and I don't understand why and how to get around this...

Comment: I assume your `script.ps1` full path has no spaces in it. What do you get in your logfile by simply running `Get-Process Outlook | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogFile`? Does it find outlook app? Are there any events in the task schedule history?

Comment: The `script.ps1` is at `c:\scripts` so regarding spaces in path should be ok :-)  
The `Get-Process Outlook` in the scheduled task return the actual process information as it should be. So yes it found the Outlook app.  
Not sure for the third question, but the scripts is fired up correctly and run correctly for all it have to do except for the `%{ $_.CloseMainWindow() }` that do nothing except return `false`  
Hope it clarify a little more the situation

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the script in task manager? Did you try putting it in a .ps1 file and running it that way?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx

**true** if the close message was successfully sent; **false** if the associated process does not have a main window or if the main window is disabled (for example if a modal dialogue is being shown).

I would fire up Windows Event Viewer and debug why the close events aren't routing or are rejected.

Comment: Know that but is there a way to make it work... Did not see nothing in event viewer or not searching for the good thing...

Answer (score 0):

I'd issue with closing the App from Jenkins bat run but when you run the same script from cmd line it works fine. Both these command work fine from cmd line but from Jenins pipeline it shows True but never closes the app.

> Get-Process App | Foreach-Object {$_.CloseMainWindow()}

> Get-Process App | % {$_.CloseMainWindow()}

> Get-Process App | ? {$_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Default}

True

Only the below approach worked from both cmd line and Jenins pipeline.

> Get-Process App | ? {$_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Host}

True

Hope this may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/859043/need-batch-file-to-close-a-window-not-the-batch-window

powershell (ps xampp-control).CloseMainWindow() written in cmd or .bat-file for xampp-control only works for me, if cmd is run as admin, because of permission problems, i had to run xampp-control.exe as admin.